# Bootstrap navbar - how to fix this layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Initial (desktop) position of elements in navbar:
the search form (on the left), and the navbar-brand used to display the date (on the right)

[image]

After collapsed I get this:

The problems:

- The date should be on the same line with the collapse button
- There should be no extra space before the date
- There should be just 1 separation border under the collapse button line

[image]

**Instead, I want to get this:**

[image]

**Is it doable?**

The code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <span class="navbar-brand navbar-right">
                {{vm.currentDate.date}}
                <span style="color: tomato">{{vm.currentDate.time}}</span>
            </span>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" target="_blank" action="https://www.google.com/search?">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="q" ng-model="vm.selected" uib-typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in vm.getSuggestions($viewValue)"
                        size="40" class="form-control gsfi" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" x-webkit-speech autofocus>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the date outside of the navbar-collapse. I would maybe put it above the button element.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="navbar-brand navbar-right">
                {{vm.currentDate.date}}
                <span style="color: tomato">{{vm.currentDate.time}}</span>
            </span>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" target="_blank" action="https://www.google.com/search?">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="q" ng-model="vm.selected" uib-typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in vm.getSuggestions($viewValue)"
                        size="40" class="form-control gsfi" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" x-webkit-speech autofocus>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]